# Calling Async Function in Angular with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In angular, a common way to call a function when a button is clicked is to write:

```
<button (click)="clickFn()">Click Me!</button>
```

Then in another file, you'd have your `clickFn()` function.

My question is: if `clickFn()` is an asynchronous function, does it need to be called differently in order for the browser to interpret it as an asynchronous function, or is it automatically called as an async function?

I've looked around in the angular docs and on stack overflow, but couldn't find anything on this question.

**Edit:**

Sure @mikeone, there are many example calls you might want to run for a button. In my project, one feature we have is allowing the user to edit their username. This needs to be asynchronous because we are sending a POST request to a database with the user's updated name and then making sure it has been received and updated before continuing. We may use a promise for this like so:

(In component.ts)

```
async changeUsername(updatedName: string){
    await new Promise((res,rej)=>{
        // * make call to database and then resolve with code 200
        ...
        res(200)
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of an ‘async function’ you would use as a click handler..?

Comment: `<button (click)="clickFn()">Click Me!</button>` this is the correct way, you don't need to do anything different for the async function browser will do by itself.

Comment: Right - well, the click handler itself cannot receive a return value (it’s just called from the DOM) - so in reality I guess it wouldn’t really make sense? If you want to perform something async after a user clicks a button you can of course do that. In your example you can simply call the tunction? Or you’ll make a click handler function that calls your actual function with an await and does something with the return?

Comment: @MikeOne you're right it doesn't really make sense to return the promise. I've removed that from my code. The function is still asynchronous, but not returning any values.

Comment: That should work fine without additional effort.

Comment: I think the way you try is antipattern. Instead you can use aysnc pipes!